# How to run feature files in Safari using WebDriverIO?

Tags: safari, webdriver-io

I'm using WebDriverIO to automate a web page, I'm able to run my feature files in Chrome but I need them to run in Safari. I'm using a Mojave 10.14.6 device. I've allowed remote automation on safari, and enabled safaridriver from terminal.

My wdio.conf.js capabilities are look like this:

```json
capabilities: [{
    maxInstances: 5,
    browserName: 'safari'
}]
```

When I run using `chrome` it works as spected but in the case of safari I get the following message:

`ERROR webdriver: RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444`

My package.json looks like this:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@wdio/cli": "^7.5.7"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^7.5.3",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^7.5.7",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^7.5.7",
    "chromedriver": "^90.0.0",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^7.0.0"
}
```

Is there any other configuration I need to add in wdio.conf.js file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is localhost (127.0.0.1) correct? Is the port 4444 correct?

Comment: Hey, I didn't check that, actually I just changed the port and it is working, thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm happy that the issue was resolved. I have written a small answer based on what we have discussed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be a problem with the port that was being used. After the port was changed from 4444 to the correct value, the issue was solved.